# Increase Width and Height of Headers in TabControl

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I don't like `TabControl`, they look ugly. So I'm creating my own custom drawn `TabControl`. I have some problems with header height. my control look like below:

[image]

Control constructor:

```
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
this.SetStyle(Conbut trolStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
this.DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
```

And `OnPaintBackground`:

```
var g = pevent.Graphics;
var Count = this.TabCount - 1;
int Offset = 2;
int index = 0;
foreach (TabPage itemtab in this.TabPages)
{
  //SizeF sz = g.MeasureString(itemtab.Text, this.Font);
  var tabrect = this.GetTabRect(index);
  var headerrect = new Rectangle(tabrect.Left + Offset, tabrect.Y, tabrect.Width, tabrect.Height);
  DrawRoundedRectangle(g, Headerbrush, headerrect, 3);
  g.DrawString(itemtab.Text, this.Font, textbrush, headerrect, str);
  if (index < Count) index++;
}
```

I tried to add this line:

```
this.ItemSize = new Size(100, 30);
```

But width returns wrong value when changing the font's size or the text of header.

[image]

Is there a way increase widths and height of header?

Comment: `ItemSize.Width` doesn't have any impact on header size, unless you set `SizeMode` to `Fixed`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To have larger tabs you can use either of these options:

1. The control automatically provide enough room for text t be drawn using the `Font` of `TabControl`. You can simply add extra room, using [`Padding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.padding?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) property. The `Padding` property specifies the amount of space around each item on the control's tab pages.
2. You can set `ItemSize` to a larger size and set `SizeMode` to `Fixed`.

`ItemSize.Width` doesn't have any impact on header width, unless you set [`SizeMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.sizemode?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) to `Fixed`. It's the reason for unexpected width which you see in your control.

Comment: SizeMode.Fixed I can't change width.But You are right.SizeMode.Fixed is better.It saved me.Thank you!accept as anser@Reza Aghaei

Comment: I prefer Normal `SizeMode` and using padding. Also use `TextRenderer.DrawText`  for drawing text.

Comment: padding of tabcontrol  applies only  to  right side (also bottom) . thats exactly what i wanted!! but this is unusual behaviour for word "padding" . its confusing

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Graphics.MeasureString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bt8ty58(v=vs.110).aspx) method to get the size (width & height) of the currently used font in order to correct the width & height of the custom drawn tab component.

Comment: If you use `Normal` as `SizeMode` of `TabControl`, the required size will be calculated automatically and you don't need to measure text. If you want to provide more space around text on header, it's enough to use suitable `Padding` for `TabControl`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need `StringFormatFlags` `NoWrap` flag to forbid multi line header. This flag is necessary for `DrawString` and `MeasureString`.

Comment: I added this.ItemsSize in constructor, NoWrap and: SizeF sz1 = g.MeasureString(this.TabPages[index].Text, this.Font); before drawstring.the text doesn't center when changing the font's size. so where is this.ItemSize?@i486

Comment: For `MeasureString` use the constructor with flags (`NoWrap`). There are also flags for centering, etc. - see `StringFormatFlags` class.